# curl downloads empty file every time

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file through curl C++ using this code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>



int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string url = "https://rtk3dsf-lb01-1291588867.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/rpgdownload?args=%7B%22ver%22:%22l.0.0.1%22,%22sid%22:28555,%22region%22:%22EUR%22,%22lang%22:%22en%22,%22token%22:%22Fqbt-EuVHsrOVeLwiVIrmXS.ck3Ph8MGH03DjKp5Q7uqYFL9CNAr9WVeyxgnHvYH6wE6RnvAtUkUMmas2N0Gj.Q**%22%7D";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "game.dat";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of downloading a 2,000 kb file it downloads a 0 kb file.
what did I do wrong?

Comment: You used `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` where you should have used `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`.

Comment: Also, you should check the return value that you store in ``res``.

Comment: I changed WRITEFUNCTION to WRITEDATA, it didn't change the result.
the value  in res is 60 which means **SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK** how do I fix that?

Comment: @Myth: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Thank you, I already got the program working by reading the data into a string and then writing the string to a file, which works better for my program anyways. but thanks for the help.